# Can't save data to the mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a simple node.js API and I created a router.post method to save data and render the saved data back. But response to the post request is like {"message":""} on hitting this url http://localhost:3000/posts (POST)
body:
{
"title":"My Post",
"description":"this is the description of my first posxsxasxt"

}

Here is the app.js file

```
const  express =require('express');

const app =express();

const mongoose=require('mongoose');

require('dotenv/config');

const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//Import Routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/posts',postsRoute);



//Routes
app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.send('We are on home');
});



//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true }, ()=>
console.log("connected to DB!")
);

//how to start listening to server

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the code for routes

```
const  express =require('express');

const router=express.Router();

const Post = require('../models/Posts');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('We are on posts');
});

router.get('/specificposts',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('We are on posts');
});


router.post('/',(req,res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });
    post.save()
    .then( data => {
        res.send(data);
       
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json({message:err});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the schema of the database

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');


//create schema

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Atlas UI
2. Click on Network Access, click on ADD IP ADDRESS and select "allow access from anywhere".